# How to run a python script when a file contains a module from different directory?

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I have the following structure:

```
|-- master.py
|-- src
| |-- configs
| | |-- _init_.py
| | |-- config.py
|-- convert_speech
| |-- _init_.py
| |-- record_audio2.py
```

Now I want to import a module from configs.config into the record_audio2.py script. I managed it to do that using this:

```
from src.configs.config import filenames
```

However when I run master.py I get the following error:

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'*

I would like to be able to run everything by running master.py as well as running record_audio2.py individually. Right now only record_audio2.py runs successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to make Python treat directories as modules, they must have an `__init__.py` file in them.

Now, when Python treats imports of modules, it uses [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) which is a list of places where to look for the files. By default, it is composed of:

1. The current directory or the directory where the file executed is
2. Your `PYTHONPATH`
3. The installation folder of your python instance

More on that [here in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

I suggest you add the path to the `src` folder to the `sys.path`, it should work like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import ..configs.config import filename
```

Comment: I get the following error from ..configs.config import filenames
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: from ..configs.config import *